# PHP SOAP Communication Using TLS 1.2

Tags: php, web-services, soap, tls1.2, ups

We have integrated **UPS Web Service** in  our site. recently we got alert from UPS :

> Effective January 26, 2016,the UPS test environment will require the
>   TLS 1.2 security protocol, and willbe available for your system
>   testing.
>
> Effective May 31, 2016,UPS will require the TLS 1.2 security protocol
>   in production. After that date,any communication requests submitted to
>   UPS using older protocols (TLS 1.1 orearlier) will fail.

My question is :

Is there any way to communicate PHP SOAP using TLS ? i have already googled a lot but could not find any solution yet.

Please suggest

Comment: [Read this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65329&edit=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Finally i got solution for this issue.It require OpenSSL > 1.0.1 or
>   NSS > 3.15 and in my case our server support SSL Version is NSS/3.19.1
>   Basic ECC so no need to change any code.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this problem as well. Here is what I use this to force TLS communication.

```php
$mode = array(
    'soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_1',  // use soap 1.1 client
    'trace' => 1,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
        array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'crypto_method' =>  STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
            )
        )
    )
);

// initialize soap client
$client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, $mode);
```

I always have a problem on my dev environment with MAMP which includes a version of openssl without TLS 1.2 support.

Comment: when i print 
$client->__getLastRequestHeaders();
$client->__getLastResponseHeaders(); 

with stream_context and without stream_context both print same result

Comment: How to check our request is being call using tsl1. 2 protocol?